# BeautifulSoup can access string indices, but my program cant

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

When I run this BeautifulSoup function in a loop to find the tag titles I can print the indices from the list it returns. When I saw this I was confused because I thought you could not put strings into any type of indices.

```
geturl = 
requests.get("https://www.techbargains.com/category/359/laptops").text
soup = bs(geturl, "html.parser")

for t in soup.find_all("a", class_ = "details"):
    print t["title"]
```

This code works fine, here is the code I wrote to try to understand how this works.

```
def listo():
    lister = ["hello", "how are you"]
    return lister


for a in listo():
    print a["hello"]
```

When I try and run it I get this error:

```
print a["hello"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What is the difference between the two? Why can Beautiful Soups function access that data but mine cant.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's not indexing with a string, it's using the string as a key to a hash table. What you are getting from Beautiful Soup is a mapping type, rather than a sequential type.

Try opening the example code that you displayed in an interpreter. Print the type of each one of the `t`'s that the soup call returns. I expect you'll find that they are dictionaries rather than lists or strings.

What you are trying to do is index inside a string using a string index, which won't work - sequential types like strings and lists can be indexed by an integer, but not by a string.

Mapping types, on the other hand, hold key-value pairs. They take something that can generate a consistent hash, and use it to look up a value. Dictionaries are the most common mapping type in Python. Other objects and classes can also implement key lookup behavior by implementing the `__getitem__(x)` magic method.

Here are links into the Python 2 standard library documentation:

Sequential types: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sequential%20types#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Mapping types - https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all` returns a list of `bs4.element.Tag` objects. In your loop you access this list's objects and by writing you get the *title* attribute of an element.

`lister = ["hello", "how are you"]` is just a list of strings